# I'd like to move the Widgets Panel to the bottom of the list in Customizer

Tags: customization, widgets

I'd prefer to have the 'new' Widgets Section/Panel (that extends to the widget areas) drop down to the bottom of list in Customizer.

I've tried:

```
$wp_customize->get_panel('widgets')->priority = 300;
--- or ---
$wp_customize->get_section('widgets')->priority = 300;
```

But neither of those lines seem to affect my target.

Anyone know what the proper ID of Widgets is?

Answer (score 0):

In case you never figured it out:

```
$wp_customize->get_panel('widgets')->priority = 300;
```